# How to save every 404 request to db

Tags: laravel, redirect, http-status-code-404

I trying to save all 404 requests as a row to the database. But can't figure out how to do it.
For example i was visited the example.com/demo but demo doesn't exist in example.com
For this situation, i need to add "demo" to the missing_pages table. I just created controller for this. But can't handle in web.php, am i need to do this with providers? middlewares? Can't do anything.

```
public function test($slug)
{
    if (empty(MissingPage::where('slug', $slug)->get())) {
        $mp = new MissingPage();
        $mp->slug = $slug;
        $mp->count = 1;
    }
    else {
        $mp = MissingPage::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $mp->increment('count');
    }
}
```

What should i do in web.php? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a fallback route, add the logic for storing the failed request in the database and then return the 404 response. For example, the route might look like this:

```php
Route::fallback('RouteNotFoundController@store')
```

Then in your controller the logic would be something like:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Save request to database as required

    abort(404)
}
```

Adding the `abort` call, it will throw the exception and render a 404 response for you.

Comment: I agree with everything @George said, plus don't forget that in order for the `fallback` route to work, it should be your last route defined in the `web.php`. Here are the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#fallback-routes

Comment: Thanks. I just learned fallback route. I like it. Trying right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can code in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    switch ($e->getStatusCode()) {
        // not found
        case 404:
            //Save to DB
            ...
            break;

        // internal error
        case 500:
            //Save to DB
            ...
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```